# JS function not changing URL in address bar

Tags: javascript, html

I've trying to design a workout website which returns exercises from a database depending on a user selection. I'm writing some test code that will change the URL in the address bar when a button is clicked if an 'Arms' checkbox is checked. However, it doesn't seem to be working so any help you can offer would be appreciated:

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
function getSelection(){
    if(document.getElementById('armsCheck').is(':checked')){
        window.location.search = "";
        window.location.href = window.location.href + "?bodypart=Arms";
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" id="armsCheck" />Arms<br />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="getSelection()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Setting `window.location.search` will re-load the page, effectively clearing any user input and causing a race against ending code execution. The same happens with `window.location.href`

Comment: I want the page reloaded with the specified addition so it will run some PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call the jQuery `is()` method on a DOM object, which doesn't have one. This would be obvious if you looked at your browser's JavaScript console.

Check the `checked` property instead.

```
if(document.getElementById('armsCheck').checked){
```

---

Also replace these lines:

```
window.location.search = "";
window.location.href = window.location.href + "?bodypart=Arms";
```

with:

```
window.location.search = "?bodypart=Arms";
```

As the first line would trigger a page reload before reaching the second line.

---

There's no need to involve JavaScript at all though. You can get the same effect with plain HTML.

```
<form>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="bodypart" value="Arms"> Arms</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Surely you meant do `window.location.search = "?bodypart=Arms"` and remove the line after; if there is already a search then you'd end up with something weird like `http://example.com/?foo?bar`

Comment: I'm afraid none of these changes made any difference and the console has not logged any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. 'getSelection()' wasn't a valid function name - thanks for your help!